# Group an array by occurrences and sort it with Lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

If have this array :

```
[
  {
    "name" : "lala",
    "source_ip" : "10.10.10.10"
  },
  {
    "name" : "lulu",
    "source_ip" : "10.10.10.11"
  },
  {
    "name" : "lolo",
    "source_ip" : "10.10.10.10"
  }
]
```

I would like to group by occurrences and sort it with Lodash to get this result :

```
[
  {
    "source_ip" : "10.10.10.10",
    "count" : 2
  },
  {
    "source_ip" : "10.10.10.11",
    "count" : 1
  },
]
```

Here is what I tried:

```
app.filter('top10', function() {
  return function(incidents) { 
    return _.chain(incidents)
        .countBy("source_ip")
        .value();
  };
});
```

I also tried to reduce before and then use **grouBy** instead but it is not working.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will help you:

```
_(array)
  .countBy("source_ip")
  .map(function(count, ip) { return { count: count, source_ip: ip }})
  .sortBy('-count')
  .value()
```

[Lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs)

**Notes:**

- `sortBy('-count')` reverse sorting by property
- `map` can iterate objects and pass to function key, so you can generate array from object
- `_()` notation means `_.chain()`

**UPDATE 2017.01.20**

We can even do it more elegant:

```
_(array)
  .countBy("source_ip")
  .invert()
  .sortBy('-count')
  .value()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! But I'm not sure that the **sortBy** is working.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Max !

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
_.countBy(array, "source_ip"); // => { 10.10.10.10: 2, 10.10.10.11: 1 }
```

If you need an array:

```
var result=[];
_.forIn(_.countBy(doc, "source_ip"), function(value, key) {
    result.push({ "source_ip": key, "count": value });
});
```